# phpmyadmin ERROR: 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm still a beginner php programmer, and am using XAMPP v1.8.3.

When I try to start phpmyadmin, it starts for a moment and then stops. This is what is says in the log:

> 9:17:39 AM  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 9:17:40 AM  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

On localhost/phpmyadmin, it says:

> Welcome to phpMyAdmin
>
> Error
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>
> The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

I look in the log, and here is the error:

> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 1474 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file D:\xampp1.8.3\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file D:\xampp1.8.3\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:33 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:34 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp1.8.3\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:35 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp1.8.3\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:36 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file D:\xampp1.8.3\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to D:\xampp1.8.3\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:36 3496 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:36 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:36 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:40 3496 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:40 3496 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:40 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:40 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:40 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:40 3496 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:40 3496 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.11 started; log sequence number 0
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:40 3496 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 339e1bc9-0065-11e3-8570-001d72ca6cfd.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Note] IPv6 is available.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' cannot be opened.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_worker_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_relay_log_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' cannot be opened.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 2013-08-08 16:00:41 3496 [Note] d:\xampp1.8.3\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>   Version: '5.6.11'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>
> 2013-08-08 16:05:17 16cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:05:17 16cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:05:17 16cc InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:06:15 16cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:06:15 16cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 16:06:15 16cc InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."account" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:15:38 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:15:38 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:15:38 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:15:38 1640 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:15:38 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:15:38 1640 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:16:08 788 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:16:08 788 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."account" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:18:24 788 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:18:24 788 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:09 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:09 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:09 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:09 1640 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:09 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:09 1640 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:33 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:33 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:33 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:33 1640 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."account" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:33 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:19:33 1640 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."account" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:21:18 788 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:21:18 788 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:21:18 788 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:21:18 788 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."account" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:21:23 16cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:21:23 16cc InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."account" index "Username_2" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:21:23 16cc InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:21:23 16cc InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."account" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:22:05 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:22:05 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:22:05 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:22:05 1640 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:22:05 1640 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:22:05 1640 InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:25:29 788 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:25:29 788 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."persons" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:25:29 788 InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
>
> 2013-08-08 22:25:29 788 InnoDB: Recalculation of persistent statistics requested for table "bank"."account" but the required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 12b4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1664679 in the ib_logfiles!
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>
> 2013-08-09 09:01:21 4912 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace bank/account uses space ID: 5 at filepath: .\bank\account.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/slave_worker_info which uses space ID: 5 at filepath: .\mysql\slave_worker_info.ibd
>
> InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\slave_worker_info.ibd
>
> InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
>
> InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
>
> InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
>
> InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
>
> InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
>
> InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
>
> InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
>
> InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
>
> InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
>
> InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
>
> InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.

It says this everytime I try to start MySQL, and I have absolutely no idea what it means.

I've tried going to the troubleshooting sites, but don't understand them.

Sorry for such a long question. I just don't know what the problem is.

Could somebody please help me with this step by step???

**Edit**

Thanks for the answer. PHPMyAdmin works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you simply can not connect to your MySQL database.  Try to connect to your MySql database directly without using phpmyadmin.  Rather connect directly.  So for example in my linux environment I would type
`mysql -uJohn -pJohnsPassword`

This is just to check if you actually can log into MySql.

Comment: There seems to be a massive amount of issues that might be the problem.  Please open your error logs and delete all the contents.  Then re-run your server.  Once you do that please output the new content to pastebin.com.  (I just want to make sure of the errors occurring).

Comment: Also what you can do, is to change the port that your server is running on.  A common issue on Windows is the conflict of ports between Skype and XAMP.

Comment: I have just saved the mysql error log to [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com) as [XAMPP 1.8.3 PHPMYADMIN / MYSQL - Jon](http://pastebin.com/Ca11K0Fz)

Comment: I just checked Skype's settings (Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection) and saw that it uses port 3916 for incoming connections, and ports 80 and 143 (same as apache server ports, not sql) as alternatives. I unchecked the checkbox next to 80 and 143, but mysql still won't start.

Comment: Ah, so there was a conflict with the ports.  There however appears to be one last problem.  So please do the following:
1.) Close down XAMPP completely and open it again but this time open it in "administrator mode" ie: right click on icon of XAMPP and choose "run-as administrator" option.
2.) If it still does not work delete the following files: .\bank\account.ibd and \mysql\slave_worker_info.ibd  !!NB!! Only do this if you have nothing of value in the database (which I am guessing it is)
3.) If it still doesn't work clear the error log, start xampp and output new errors to pastebin